# Function not defined when function is defined?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have the function defined as `connectAcocunt()` in my `script.js` file that I am trying to call from my `index.html` file on button press, that is imported with the line `<script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`, but for some reason console is telling my that the function `connectAcocunt()` is not defined.

Ive been trying for 3 days now. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code as requested.

```js
function connectAcocunt(){
  //if the window has no ethereum property then prompt to install metamask else get run the getAccount function
  if (typeof window.ethereum !== 'undefined') {
    getAccount()
  } else {
      alert('Please make sure MetaMask in installed.');
  }
}

async function getAccountBalance(){
  web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
  var accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log(web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]))
}

async function func(){
//the paremeter functions
const transactionParameters = {
nonce: '0x00', // ignored by MetaMask
gasPrice: '0x55F0', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
gas: '0x55F0', // customizable by user during MetaMask confirmation.
to: '0xfa7679267a57b463c95fc208d3eec0635b8238cc', // Required except during contract publications.
from: ethereum.selectedAddress, // must match user's active address.
value: '0x58D15E17628000', // Only required to send ether to the recipient from the initiating external account.
chainId: '0x3', // Used to prevent transaction reuse across blockchains. Auto-filled by MetaMask.
};

const txHash = await ethereum.request({
method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
params: ['transactionParameters'],
})
}

async function getAccount() {
//selecting the show account class in main html
const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');
//getting accounts from metamask
const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
//selecting the first one
const account = accounts[0];
//setting the show account class text as the frist metamask acount
showAccount.innerHTML = account;
//setting the connect button text to the account adress
document.getElementById("connect").innerHTML = account.substr(0, 3)+ '...'+ account.substr(38, 42);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Optimistic Apes</title>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="connect" class="button" onclick="connectAcocunt();">Connect</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="func();">Mint NFT</button>
  <h2>Account: <span class="showAccount"></span></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js file

Comment: Could you share your JS code as well as the HTML structure you're using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @vasilis g., the code has been uplaoded.

Comment: `connectAcocunt` is not spelled right.. But you do it twice. Please check over the spellings and make sure this isn't your problem.

Comment: It is spelled the same between the HTMl and Js, so shouldn't matter?

Comment: Shouldn't matter in this case, but it's not how you spelled it in your question and it seems obviously wrong, so its work checking that you are consistent in all places.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it works fine to be, on condition that there is no spelling error.

Comment: So this code works for you?

Comment: Testing it on JSFiddle seems to be working for the example provided.

Comment: Strange, not working at all for me. Im using node js http-server as testing server, let me try jsfiddle

Comment: My guess is that you haven't done a full refresh (Ctrl-Shift-R) since you changed the js file.  Doing a simple refresh won't reload the external dependencies, like scripts and images.

Comment: The code should work given the path of the script is correct `... src="script.js"`

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts, that was it, can believe that I spend 3 days breaking my head over this. I knew I did everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that I didnt fully refresh, a regular refresh did not update the script. By pressing ctrl+shift+r I was able to solve the problem